# How can pass data to routeroutlet

Tags: angular, frontend

I want share this question to developers with experience 
Does the Subject behavior of Rxjs the best practice to pass data to routeroutler or there are other solutions  
I want to pass data from parent to child as router-outlet like this:

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>Position</nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>
    <router-outlet [data] = "data"></router-outlet>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

and accept data using @input() or I should use a service to share the data

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service to share the data to your components. It is not possible to pass data to `@Input()` variables in components injected by angular router. The only possibility you have is to pass data to the route (in route config). Unfortunately this is only feasible for static data, but not for dynamic values. You have to use a service in order to get this working.